# Unable to load Python dependencies with Serverless Framework for AWS Lambda: Error: STDOUT

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

This should be fairly straightfoward (I think). I've been using Serverless Framework for the past several months without much issue, and have been able to load packages such as pandas and numpy, but had recently tried loading `email` and `sklearn` and received the bellow message when I try to deploy the stack.

```
 Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: STDOUT:

  STDERR: Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640
      at C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:325:13
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at installRequirements (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:312:28)
      at installRequirementsIfNeeded (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:556:3)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.installAllRequirements (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\lib\pip.js:635:29)
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.tryCatcher (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
      at _drainQueue (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\schuy\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:137:15)
```

I retried deploying the stack with just `numpy`, `pandas`, and `datetime` and had no issues/errors, but adding `email` or `sklearn` creates this error message.

Any idea on how to resolve this and I can load those packages into my Lambda Function with Serverless Framework?

**Edit**
As requested the Yaml file. Although this worked with other dependencies/packages I've worked before

```
service: new-process-5

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

resources:
  Resources:
    aaaaincomingcsv:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
      Properties: {}
    aaaaprocessedsalestotal:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
      Properties: 
        BucketName: aaaa-processed-salestotalv5
    aaaaprocessedwinloss:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
      Properties: 
        BucketName: aaaa-processed-winlossgroupedv5
    aaaaemployeesstargetotal:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
      Properties: 
        BucketName: aaaa-employees-stagetotalv5
    aaaaemployeesalespivot:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
      Properties: 
        BucketName: aaaa-employees-salespivotv5



provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: us-east-1
  profile: serverless-admin
  timeout: 500
  memorySize: 128
  iamRoleStatements:
   - Effect: "Allow"
     Action:
       - "s3:*"
     Resource: "*"


functions:
  csv-processor:
    handler: handler.featureengineering
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: aaaaincomingcsvv5
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - suffix: .csv

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
  dockerizePip: true


plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

**additional edit**

I corrected for the lack of indentation under custom and python requirements but still receiving an error message.

Comment: Can you share your serverless.yml file?

Comment: @Erico done. I didn't originally add it because didn't have issues with the dependencies I described before: numpy, pandas, datetime.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if that would solve the problem, but the dependency is not done on docker because it's not indented correctly. `dockerizePip: true` needs to be under `pythonRequirements`. You definitely need to dockerize that specially because you're running on Windows.

Comment: @Erico I fixed the indentation but am still getting the error message and the stack is not deploying. Weird. One thing to note, I've never used the `email` package before except wanting to use it for this project. Is there something perhaps idiosyncratic to that which won't cause it to load?

Comment: That's odd, is it the exactly same error? If I'm not mistaken the dependency tree is installed from docker and it should show the error from the container, not from your Windows host.